# Pythonanywhere MySQL connection

Tags: python, mysql, bottle, pythonanywhere

I'm new to pythonanywhere and am currently deploying my first app with it and the bottle framework. I have created a db with the online console but I don't know the syntax for accessing it. Is it the same syntax as when deploying locally? Or is it something else? MySQLdb has been imported... Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Reading help for PythonAnywhere and for MySQLdb package is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [page on using MySQL at PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/UsingMySQL). It suggests to use the following configuration for django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<your_username>$<your_database_name>',
        'USER': '<your_username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<your_mysql_password>',
        'HOST': 'mysql.server',
    }
}
```

And I'm almost entirely sure that these credentials will be acceped by [MySQLdb driver](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

```
db=MySQLdb.connect(
    host='mysql.server',
    user='<your_username>',
    passwd='<your_mysql_password>',
    db='<your_username>$<your_database_name>')
```

Comment: Thanks VLadimir, I had some similar to that, but when I use db_mysqlconnect(host='mysql.server', user='<your_username>', passwd='<your_mysql_password>', db='<your_username>$<your_database_name>') I get an error "undefined name '_mysql'", any thoughts?

Comment: From documentation on MySQL: If you want to write applications which are portable across databases, use MySQLdb, and avoid using this module directly. Code fixed.

Comment: Apologies my password was wrong, thanks a million for your help :)